# Converting JSON output to HTML table through PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, html

I'm currently lost on how to do this and need help but I'm currently building an ionic app and storing information on a database when fetching that information back through the PHP script I'm recieving JSON which I would like to convert to a nice formatted HTML table

Here is my PHP

```
<?php           
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$host = "****";
$user = "*****";
$password = "";
$database = "holes";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die("Problem connecting.");

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * from hole18") or die("Bad Query.");

mysqli_close($connect);

$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $results[] = $row; 
}

echo json_encode($results);
    ?>
```

And here's the Json output:

```
 [{"index":"1","Par":"4","FIR":"1","GIR":"1","Score":"3","puttsno":"1","bunkershit":"0","oob":"0"}]
```

Please help me

Comment: Try this: `$json = file_get_contents('url_here'); $obj = json_decode($json); echo $obj->index;` where `url_here` will be the path of the php file you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<table>
<?php
    $json_result = json_encode($results); 
    $json_dec_result = json_decode( $json_result );

    if ( !empty( $json_dec_result) ) 
    {
        foreach ($json_dec_result as $field_name => $field_value) 
        {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo  $field_name;?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo  $field_value;?>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
            <?php 
        }
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Would that be situated in between the original <?php tags ? or do i put that code that you provided after the php I have, outside the tags?

Comment: @ShaneGleeson You can do everything inside your first pair of tags, just convert the `<table>` tags to `echo "<table>";` and such

Answer (score 1):

Uttam's answer will work to get an HTML table server response from your PHP code. That may be all you need but if you are using Ionic then the more appropriate method is probably to still stick with the JSON response, load that into your controller and use ng-repeat with a data grid to display it as HTML.

See this if you are interested: [creating a table in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215355/creating-a-table-in-ionic)

Comment: Do you know how I would go about taking for example my JSON code above, using index, Par, Fir etc... as the headers and the details that go with them that are in the database to output underneath them? ..  I would use the ionic ng repeat if I knew how to use it properly

Comment: Most of what you need should be in the link but if I get a chance I'll have a crack at creating some example code at some point over the next few days. I'd like to learn Ionic properly as well (I know Javascript, jQuery and PHP fairly well but not Ionic / Bootstrap) so it will be a nice exercise for me.